# Issues with pushing DetailViewController and UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue, viewdidload

**update**

```
DetailViewController *wordDetail = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
wordDetail.wordWordString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"word"]];
wordDetail.wordDefinitionString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"definition"]];
wordDetail.title = [[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
```

here's my new prepare for segue (did you mean i dont need that anymore if i use the above method, or at all? Im actually now sure if all my identifiers are lining up... what do you think?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
if ([[showDetail] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
```

Figure it might help to see my DetailViewController.m too...

```
-(void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}

if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}        
}

-(void)configureView
{
//Update the user interface for the detail item.

if (self.detailItem) {
    self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
}
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    wordWordLabel.text = wordWordString;
    wordDefinitionLabel.text = wordDefinitionString;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first section of code is fine. However it is creating a DetailViewController then pushing it along. This means there never is a Segue so your second code doesn't matter at all. You need to decide which you'd like to use.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:wordDetail animated:YES];
```

This line pushes a viewController on the stack. OR

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail sender:self];
```

will use the segue in Storyboards named showDetail. You can't have both, you'll need to choose.

**Storyboard Identifier**
[image: Storyboard Identifier]

Comment: alright. edits made to original question. thank you. i dont know what the identifier would be.

Comment: The identifier is something you setup in Storyboard. Click on the segue you created in you Storyboard then in the inspector on the right you'll find an Identifier field you can fill in.

Comment: I added a screenshot that should help you find it.

Comment: ok its called showDetail. the code works. so i updated my code and included my detailvewcontroller.m. i think thats why my data isnt being populated correctly.